# multi-container under one endpoint Sagemaker issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-sagemaker, endpoint

I am implementing the 2 models one is fraud detection and other is SVM, but multi-container is giving an error on the health check. Implementing the docker one by one is working but integration with the single endpoint is not working.

Comment: Maybe with both model you do not have enough memory to load them. Have you checked the memory consumption in the cloudwatch metrics. What instance are you using for the deployment

Comment: the error is cannot find the directory opt/ml/model/model.joblib

Comment: Ah ok so it seam that your model artifact has not been attached correctly to the docker. I guess that model.joblib is your model file. I would implement a small python script that searches for that file and print the filepath to the stdout. And than take a look into the log to see if the model has been mounted under another directory

Comment: yes model.joblib is model file, when i test this locally it is creating and I am able to find the model file in the expected folder